# RxJava issue with zip operator

Tags: java, rx-java

I am facing issue with zip operation, I have 3 Observables that I am combining with zip operator. The problem is sometimes the statement in the subscribe code does not get executed. Is the zip operator not supposed to wait for all the observable to emit the event. Below is the sample code.

```
import java.util.Date;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
public class ZipRxJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZipRxJava z = new ZipRxJava();
        Observable<CartPlanResponse> o1 = Observable.<CartPlanResponse>create(sub -> sub.onNext(createPlanResponse(z))).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        Observable<CartFeatureResponse> o2 = Observable.<CartFeatureResponse>create(sub -> sub.onNext(createFeatureResponse(z))).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        Observable<CartAccessoriesResponse> o3 = Observable.<CartAccessoriesResponse>create(sub -> sub.onNext(createAccessoriesResponse(z))).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        Observable.zip(o1, o2, o3, (p1, p2, p3) -> {
            System.out.println("Inside Transformer $$$$$$$$$$$››››" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Response res = z.new Response();
            res.setPlanResponse(p1);
            res.setFeatureResponse(p2);
            res.setAccesoriesResponse(p3);
            return res;
        }).subscribe(r1 -> System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&"+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + "*******" +  r1.getPlanResponse().getPlanId() + " " + r1.getFeatureResponse().getFeatureId() + " " +
            r1.getAccesoriesResponse().getAccessoryId()), e1 -> System.out.println("Error"));
        System.out.println("Main Method ********** " + Thread.currentThread().getName());   
    }


    private static CartPlanResponse createPlanResponse(ZipRxJava z) {
        System.out.println("Plan ********** " + Thread.currentThread().getName());  
        CartPlanResponse res = z.new CartPlanResponse();
        res.setPlanId("123");
        System.out.println("Before Return Plan ********** " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return res;
    }

    private static CartFeatureResponse createFeatureResponse(ZipRxJava z) {
        System.out.println("Feature ********** " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        //sleep();
        int y =0;
        for (int i =0 ; i <100000000; i++) {
            y +=i;
        }
        CartFeatureResponse res = z.new CartFeatureResponse();
        res.setFeatureId("345");
        System.out.println("Before Return Feature ********** " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return res;
    }

    private static CartAccessoriesResponse createAccessoriesResponse(ZipRxJava z) {
        System.out.println("Accessories ********** " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        CartAccessoriesResponse res = z.new CartAccessoriesResponse();
        res.setAccessoryId("567");
        System.out.println("Before Return Accessories ********** " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return res;
    }

    private static void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class CartPlanResponse {
        String planId;

        public String getPlanId() {
            return planId;
        }

        public void setPlanId(String planId) {
            this.planId = planId;
        }   
    }

    private class CartFeatureResponse {
        private String featureId;

        public String getFeatureId() {
            return featureId;
        }

        public void setFeatureId(String featureId) {
            this.featureId = featureId;
        }
    }

    private class CartAccessoriesResponse {
        private String accessoryId;

        public String getAccessoryId() {
            return accessoryId;
        }

        public void setAccessoryId(String accessoryId) {
            this.accessoryId = accessoryId;
        }
    }

    private class Response {
        private CartPlanResponse planResponse;
        private CartFeatureResponse featureResponse;
        private CartAccessoriesResponse accesoriesResponse;
        public CartPlanResponse getPlanResponse() {
            return planResponse;
        }
        public void setPlanResponse(CartPlanResponse planResponse) {
            this.planResponse = planResponse;
        }
        public CartFeatureResponse getFeatureResponse() {
            return featureResponse;
        }
        public void setFeatureResponse(CartFeatureResponse featureResponse) {
            this.featureResponse = featureResponse;
        }
        public CartAccessoriesResponse getAccesoriesResponse() {
            return accesoriesResponse;
        }
        public void setAccesoriesResponse(CartAccessoriesResponse accesoriesResponse) {
            this.accesoriesResponse = accesoriesResponse;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sleep in the main method because RxJava Schedulers run on daemon threads which stop and don't execute work if the main thread quits in your case:

```
    System.out.println("Main Method ********** " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    sleep();
```

Prints:

```
Plan ********** RxIoScheduler-2
Before Return Plan ********** RxIoScheduler-2
Feature ********** RxIoScheduler-3
Main Method ********** main
Accessories ********** RxIoScheduler-4
Before Return Accessories ********** RxIoScheduler-4
Before Return Feature ********** RxIoScheduler-3
Inside Transformer $$$$$$$$$$$››››RxIoScheduler-3
&&&&&&&&&&&RxIoScheduler-3*******123 345 567
```

Comment: The problem is I cannot use sleep method because I am running it from web application. All the 3 Observable codes are calling other microservices and if I put debugger in Observable 2 code my service is returning response, but If I remove the debugger the service is returning error response that service in Observable 2 is not available. With debugger the zip operation is waiting for Observable 2 to emit message but without the debugger the zip operation is assuming that Observable 2 is in error and hence it is returning error.

Comment: This requirement was not in the question?! You have to block in some way, for example havin `toBlocking().subscribe()` instead of plain `subscribe()`.